# How to write data to a csv list with if statements

Tags: python

I am trying to write data to a csv to a new field/column with if statements (based on values already present in the list).  I have a list of UIDs (Field name Class):
    ACRW,
    AOC,
    IFSE,
    LN,
    RLW,
    etc,

This is what I have so far:

```
import csv
with open('PythonProject.csv', 'r') as rd_list:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(rd_list)
    with open ('new_rdlist.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Class', 'Description', 'Flex']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter (new_csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        csv_writer = csv.writer(new_csvfile)
        Class = ''
        for row in csv_reader:
            if Class == 'C':
                value = 'Cable'
            elif Class == 'W':
                value = 'Wave'
            elif Class == 'RT':
                value = 'Therm'
            elif Class == 'H':
                value = 'Heat'
            else:
                value = 'Unit'
            csv_writer.writerow(row)            
input('\nNew List is in your directory, Press Enter to exit')
```

Expected result is to have the csv populate to be,
    Class, Description, Flex (which is the new field)
    (ACRW, unique name, Unit)
    (AOC, unique name, Unit)
    (C, unique name, Cable)
    (IFSE, unique name, Unit)
    (LN, unique name, Unit)
    (RLW, unique name, Unit)
    (W, unique name, Wave)
    etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood you right, I assume you intend to read in the `"PythonProject.csv"` and write the same data with an *additional* column to `"new_rdlist.csv"`.

**Accessing & Manipulating the data**

The main issue seems to be understanding rows in `DictReader` and `DictWriter`. As you are already using `DictWriter` I suggest using the `DictReader` class as well. The cells/fields in each row can be accessed by their column names. You can access the "Class" value that way, so the first check would read:

```
if row["Class"] == "C":
  value = "Cable"
```

you can even directly manipulate the row dictionary:

```
if row["Class"] == "C":
  row["Flex"] = "Cable"
```

After that modification the rest should be easy to solve!

**Other issues**

`csv_writer = csv.writer(new_csvfile)` is redundant as it overwrites the `csv_writer` variable again

**(Almost) final code**

```
import csv
with open('PythonProject.csv', 'r') as rd_list:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(rd_list)
    with open ('new_rdlist.csv', 'w', newline='') as new_csvfile:
        fieldnames = ['Class', 'Description', 'Flex']
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter (new_csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        for row in csv_reader:
            if row["Class"] == "C":
                row["Flex"] = "Cable"
            ...
                row["Flex"] = "Unit"
            csv_writer.writerow(row)            
input('\nNew List is in your directory, Press Enter to exit')
```